# returning one between three int possibilities after Json

Tags: java, android, json

I am doing an android login call to an API, the response could be two different json:

A.- Json Error
 {"message":" not found","error":"Unauthorized","status":401}

B.-Json Success
 {"permissions":10,"ac_status":"active"}

My idea is return to the main Screen one of this three (int) values after check the Json tags:

return 0 if error getting JSON (like server down)
return 1 if login success
return 2 if error in login (sever error , JSON null)

I am trying something like this on an AsyncTask,it works but I always get 0 on server error and login success. How I can do it? thanks in advanced.

```
@Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
...
...

int valueReturn =0;
JSONObject response = jsonService.call(url);

 try {
   if (response.getString("TAG_ERROR")
     valueReturn = 2;
   else
     valueReturn= 1;

   } catch (JSONException e) {
     valueReturn = 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> works but I always get 0 on server error and login success.

Because `TAG_ERROR` key not exists in provided JSON Strings so control always going in catch block.

```
 How I can do it?
```

Use [JSONObject.has(String KEY_NAME)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to check if key exists or not before accessing value as:

```
if (response.has("error"){

   // server error
}else if (response.has("ac_status"){
      // login success
}else{

//error getting Json

}
```